# Entity Framework - Code First - Entity Splitting When There Is No Shared Primary Key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have an existing database with the following tables:

```
Customer
   customer_id (PK)
   customer_name

Customer Address
   customer_address_id (PK)
   customer_id (FK)
   address_id (FK)
   address_type

Address
   address_id (PK)
   street
   city
   state
   country
   postal_code
```

I have an Address domain class as follows:

```
public class Address {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int CustomerId {get; set;}
   public int AddressId {get; set;}
   public int AddressType {get; set;}
   public string Street {get; set;}
   public string City{get; set;}
   public string State{get; set;}
   public string Country{get; set;}
   public string PostalCode{get; set;}
}
```

I wanted to give code-first a try to see if I can split the Address domain class when saving so that data gets persisted into the appropriate tables. Since CustomerAddress and Address tables do not share a common key, this is not so straight forward. The only way I can think of is to create a set of classes specific for code first and map it back to my Address domain class.

Is there any way I can achieve entity splitting without having to create additional code-first specific classes?

Comment: You want to split address up into 2 tables?

Comment: If the `Address` class already has `CustomerId`, why you need a `Customer_Address` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a relation between the two tables. You should model your tables as follows:

```
public class CustomerAddress {
   [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id {get; set;}

   public int CustomerId {get; set;}

   [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
   public Customer Customer

   public int AddressId {get; set;}

   [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
   public Address Address

   public int AddressType {get; set;}
}

public class Address {
   [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id {get; set;}

   public string Street {get; set;}

   public string City{get; set;}

   public string State{get; set;}

   public string Country{get; set;}

   public string PostalCode{get; set;}
}
```